How do i get the number of daily downloads for my android App?
I am trying to get the number of daily downloads my android app on the play store has, to display on a dashboard. Is there an API available by google to get this metric?
I've looked into the google reporting API and the Google.Apis.Playdeveloperreporting.v1alpha1.Data, Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3 Nuget packages, but I am unable to get daily downloads.
